# Is there any information about the changes to the Onmibus edition of Empire of the East?

Tags: fred-saberhagen, empire-of-the-east

Fred Saberhagen's *[Empire of the East](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empire_of_the_East_series)* was originally three novels.  However, it is much easier nowadays to find an omnibus edition containing the whole story--albeit with some significant changes (The one-volume editions often have covers that make it look like a totally generic fantasy work, which it certainly is not.)

My question about this has two parts.  First, is there any information from Saberhagen about why he made the changes he did?  Some of the reasons may seem relatively obvious, such as wanting to include Draffut, who was probably the best character in the whole series (which ran to more than fifteen books, counting all the *Books of Swords*).  But there seemed to be a lot of just minor excisions; lots of little bits of color I remembered from when I first read the trilogy were not there int the omnibus.

Second, is there any information about exactly what the changes were--a complete concordance somewhere?  I have tried to locate one on the Internet, but I was unable.